# regex remove line in tag while maintaining other tags

Tags: php, regex, xml, newline

I have a huge XML document, which I want clean up since a text editor has added wordwrap to it, for no reason.

So partial XML code looks like this:

```
<ProfileFolder name="I/O">
<Allowed display="I/O" value="I/O"/>
<Allowed display="I/O, I/O connector"
value="4pin I/O connector"/>
<Allowed display="I/O, I/O connector"
value="6pin I/O connector"/>
<Allowed display="I/O, I/O connector"
value="configurable I/O connectors"/>
<Allowed display="I/O, I/O connector"
value="fixed I/O connectors"/>
<Allowed value="pin numbers above"/>
<Allowed value="pin numbers below"/>
<Allowed display="I/O, I/O connector" value="relay ports"/>
<Allowed display="VoIP" value="call button"/>
</ProfileFolder>
```

And I want to remove the linebreak inside the tags, so instead of:

```
<Allowed display="I/O, I/O connector"
value="fixed I/O connectors"/>
```

I want:

```
<Allowed display="I/O, I/O connector" value="fixed I/O connectors"/>
```

I really hate RegEx, even though it's very very powerful, and I can't figure out the correct format of the RegEx code.

I've tried:

```
<(.*)\n(.*)?\/>
```

and

```
(?<=>)(.*)\n(.*)\/>
```

(Which was the closest, but opposite of what I want) :)

Currently using Sublime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something as simple as this:

```
\n(?!<)
```

should work for your case. This regex means newlines that are not followed by a `<` character.

You can find this and replace with a single space.

Comment: well i actually did. with the snippet the op posted and using sublime text, as op stated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a XML Parser:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $xml );
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Will output:

```
(...)
<Allowed display="I/O, I/O connector" value="4pin I/O connector"/>
<Allowed display="I/O, I/O connector" value="6pin I/O connector"/>
(...)
```

`SimpleXML` removes by default all newlines inside tag declarations.

Comment: Would work, but since I'm not using PHP this doesn't help me, but I'll keep that one in mind, since I will parse this xml document with php later, to grab information from it.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll have use for that information in another situation I'm in :)

Answer (score 0):

This will also work

```
(?<!>)\n
```

*Regex Explanation*

```
(?<!>)\n #Assure that the line does not end with > followed by a \n.
```

So if the line satisfies the above condition, merge the lines

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was easy... just couldn't wrap my mind around it.